# Python - How to plot argument in integral that is not the value being integrated

Tags: python, plot, scipy, integral

I want to integrate a function that has no closed form solution with an unknown variable and then plot vs the unknown variable. To try a simpler test, I tried to use the integral of `f(x,c) = (x^2+c)`, integrated with respect to `x` and plot with different values of `c`.  However, the code below gets the error

> only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

even though the integral of a number, e.g. `integral(5)`, seems to return the correct scalar value.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate


def f(x,c):
    return x**2+c

def integral(c):
    return integrate.quad(f,0,10, args = (c,))[0]
y = np.linspace(0,20,200)


plt.plot(y, integral(y))
```

Comment: You really shouldn't write a function called `int`. It creates needless confusion with [the built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: What is your variable `test` ?

Comment: I guess `test` should be `f` since it is the function defined above

Comment: edited to change int function to integral and fixed the test typo

Answer (score 1):

You pass a numpy array as the argument `c` while you wanted to integrate over `x` for all the items of `c`. Therefore you can use this:

```
def f(x,c):
    return x**2+c

def integrate_f(c):
    result = np.zeros(len(c))
    counter = 0
    for item in c:
        result[counter] = integrate.quad(f,0,10, args = (item))[0]
        counter +=1
    return result

c_array = np.linspace(0,1,200)
plt.plot(c_array, integrate_f(c_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

onno was a bit faster. But here is my similar solution. You need to loop over all the different `c`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate


def f(x,c):
    return x**2+c

def getIntegral(c_list):
    result = []
    for c in c_list:
        integral = integrate.quad(f,0,10,args = c)[0]
        result.append(integral)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":


    c_list = np.linspace(0,20,200)

    plt.plot(c_list, getIntegral(c_list))
    plt.show()
```